Can I compost fruit infested with monilia?
Some of my apples have the typical signs of monilia rot. I have a compost bin, but it typically does not reach high temperatures, so I am somewhat worried about spreading monilia spores all over my garden if I put monilia-infested apples in the bin and use the resulting compost in my garden.
Are monilia-infested apples (and other fruit) safe to put in a cold compost pile, or do I need to dispose of them safely?

Compost should be fine, but I would cover the apple with a layer of other stuffs. Monilia is already around your garden, so just reduce as much as possible the spread of new spores. Probably on next few years you should apply some anti-fungal (organic or non-organic), and this winter remove carefully all fruits, and rack all leaves (again try to over with an additional layer). Possibly also some winter anti-fungal on branches and trunk.
Note: I use a generic term anti-fungal, but you should get local advice, because the correct anti-fungal depends on location (weather), the type of monilia, and availability (on small quantities).
